# Proving $\frac 12+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(5+6n)(7+6n)}=\frac{\pi}6$ without Leibniz

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, pi

> Show that $$\frac 12+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(5+6n)(7+6n)}=\frac{\pi}6$$

My proof uses the Leibniz series, $$1-\frac 13+\frac 15-\frac 17+\frac 19-\frac 1{11}+\cdots = \frac{\pi}4$$

---

\begin{align*}&\qquad 1-\frac 13+\frac 15-\frac 17+\frac 19-\frac 1{11}+\cdots \\ &= 1+\bigg(\frac 15-\frac 17\bigg)-\bigg(\frac 1{11}-\frac 1{13}\bigg)+\cdots -\bigg(\frac 13-\frac 19+\frac 1{15}-\frac 1{21}+\cdots\bigg) \\ &= 1+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{(5+6n)(7+6n)}-\frac{\pi}{12}\end{align*} $$\therefore \frac 12+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{(5+6n)(7+6n)}=\frac{\pi}6$$

---

My question is, how would one solve the problem without the Leibniz series? If one didn't know of the series, I'm not asking for a way to solve the problem through deriving the series first, I'm asking for a way to solve the problem without using the series at all.

I am curious because using the series the proof is incredibly short, clever and elegant. Thus, to me, it begs the question on how to solve the problem without the series, whilst still keeping clever and elegant (concision aside). I have no idea, hence why I have posted a question here. I assume some creativity is perhaps involved, vaguely speaking I suppose. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @KentaS I'm not sure. My knowledge in infinite series and similar generating functions is scarcely limited. But... nonrigorously at least, it seemed to work :/

Comment: The Leibniz series is actually the Taylor series expansion for $\arctan x$, with $x = 1$. Not sure if that helps though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(6n+5)(6n+7)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{6n+5}-\frac1{6n+7}\right)
=\frac12\int_0^1(t^{6n+4}-t^{6n+6})\,dt=\frac12\int_0^1t^{6n+4}(1-t^2)\,dt$$
So
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+5)(6n+7)}
=\frac12\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{6n+4}(1-t^2)\,dt
=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{t^4(1-t^2)}{1+t^6}\,dt$$
and now you have a nice integral to do.

Comment: How did you get from $\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{6n+4}(1-t^2)\,dt
=\int_0^1\frac{t^4(1-t^2)}{1+t^6}\,dt$? Thanks for the rest of the answer though, and yes it is a cool integral, even nicer with $u=t^2$ and $du = 2t\, dt$.

Comment: (actually I might ignore $u=t^2$ and substitute $t=\tan \frac u2$ instead)

Comment: It's a geometric progression.

Comment: I see. Thank you and congrats on the checkmark :)